# Javascript style using getBoundingClientRect not working

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to use `getBoundingClientRect` javascript function but the problem is this only seems to work for 1 of my elements. Here is the code.

```
function getDataXML(getID, cellId) {

    var divMain = document.getElementById('Main');
    var divCell = document.getElementById(cellId);
    var divHoverControl = document.getElementById(getID);

    var rectMain = divHoverControl.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rectCell = divCell.getBoundingClientRect();

    var divWidth = divHoverControl.offsetWidth;
    var cellWidth = divCell.offsetWidth;

    alert(rectMain.left + "  " + rectMain.right + " " + divWidth + "  " + cellWidth);
    }
```

Its seems as though the page gets the elements using there ID correctly as I get no error and setting some style attributes works for each element but I only seem to get a result for my rectCell and cellWidth variables but the exact same code for rectMain and DivWidth dont seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.